# Problema com condicional de display no Js

Tags: javascript

Estou tentando criar um condicional com `display: block;` e `display: none;` mas o JS não está trazendo o valor do display css do meu elemento `#slide`.

Qual o problema?

```
var slider = document.getElementById('slide');
if(slider.style.display == 'block'){
   alert('teste');
}
```

Comment: Você pode adicionar o/um trecho do html?

Answer (score 5):

Uma causa bastante provável é que a propriedade `display` esteja na verdade em branco. Uma solução simples é inverter a lógica:

```
var slider = document.getElementById('slide');
if(slider.style.display !== 'none'){
   alert('visível');
} else {
   alert('oculto');    
}
```

Comment: Esse comportamento é meio inesperado para mim: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7LMfH/1/). Entendi algo errado?

Comment: @GuilhermeBernal Os valores só estarão visíveis se forem setados como propriedades do elemento (ex: `el.style.display`). Quando você atribui via CSS, é preciso pegar o valor computado, com [`getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.getComputedStyle) + polyfill se necessário. http://jsfiddle.net/7LMfH/2/